# How to avoid registrations result when query the entities filtered by a relationship

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I've deployed the iot stack with docker. These are the used containers:

- fiware/orion:2.0.0
- fiware/iotagent-json:1.8.0

[other containers not involved in the issue ...]

Documentation consulted:

- http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/

---

**Step 1:** I've registered the following entities on the **Orion context broker**:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:1026/v2/op/update/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: test' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "actionType": "append",
  "entities": [{
      "type": "Area",
      "id": "first:Area:001",
      "name": {
          "type": "Text",
          "value": "First area"
      }
  }, {
      "type": "Area",
      "id": "second:Area:002",
      "name": {
          "type": "Text",
          "value": "Second area"
      }
  }]
}'
```

---

**Step 2:** I've registered the following device related with the Area **first:Area:001** on the **IoT agent**:

```
curl -X POST \
http://localhost:4041/iot/devices \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'fiware-service: test' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
-d '{
    "devices": [{
        "device_id": "device001",
        "entity_name": "first:Area:001:IoTDevice:001",
        "entity_type": "IoTDevice",
        "transport": "HTTP",
        "protocol": "IoTA-JSON",
        "endpoint": "http://context-producer:3000/iot/iot-device/device001",
        "commands": [{
            "name": "ping",
            "type": "command"
        }],
        "attributes": [{
            "object_id": "c",
            "name": "count",
            "type": "Number"
        }],
        "static_attributes": [{
                "name": "refArea",
                "type": "Relationship",
                "value": "first:Area:001"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "Text",
                "value": "IoT Device 001"
            }
        ]
    }]
}'
```

---

**Request 1:** When you perform **step 2**, **registration-type** entities are automatically generated on the **Orion context broker**

```
curl -X GET \
http://localhost:1026/v2/registrations/ \
-H 'fiware-service: test' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /'
```

**Result:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "5bd6dbb2bef7081490c96eb2",
        "dataProvided": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "first:Area:001:IoTDevice:001",
                    "type": "IoTDevice"
                }
            ],
            "attrs": [
                "ping"
            ]
        },
        "provider": {
            "http": {
                "url": "http://iotagent-json:4041"
            },
            "supportedForwardingMode": "all",
            "legacyForwarding": true
        },
        "status": "active"
    }
]
```

---

**Test 1:** Getting the **IoTDevice-type** entities related with the Area **first:Area:001**

```
curl -X GET \
'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities?options=keyValues&q=refArea==first:Area:001' \
-H 'fiware-service: test' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /'
```

**OK Expected Result:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "first:Area:001:IoTDevice:001",
        "type": "IoTDevice",
        "TimeInstant": " ",
        "count": 0,
        "name": "IoT Device 001",
        "ping_info": " ",
        "ping_status": "UNKNOWN",
        "refArea": "first:Area:001",
        "ping": ""
    }
]
```

---

**Test 2:** Getting the **IoTDevice-type** entities related with the Area **second:Area:001**

```
curl -X GET \
'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities?options=keyValues&q=refArea==second:Area:001' \
-H 'fiware-service: test' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /'
```

**ERROR unexpected Result:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "first:Area:001:IoTDevice:001",
        "type": "IoTDevice",
        "ping": ""
    }
]
```

> The expected result was [ ] or empty but the query returned results that seem to come from the **registration-type** entities. This only happens if devices with attributes of type **command** are inserted. For example, **the ping command**.
>
> **So, How can this be avoided?**

Answer (score 1):

According to [Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/context_providers/index.html):

> Query filtering (e.g. `GET /v2/entities?q=temperature>40`) is not supported on query forwarding. First, Orion doesn't include the filter in the `POST /v1/queryContext` operation forwarded to CPr. Second, Orion doesn't filter the CPr results before responding them back to client. An issue corresponding to this limitation has been created: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2282

That may be the cause of the problem.

While the issue gest solved the workaround is to filter (by `refArea==second:Area:001` in your case) at client side.

Comment: Thanks, @fgalan, I have reduced the impact of this problem by simply checking if each result has a "name" attribute.

I will be attentive to a solution.